# Titanium - Android - Using scroll view

Tags: android, titanium

I'm trying to prepare mobile app that runs on Android and iOS using Titanium Appcelerator 
In one of the view, i'll send a request to server, get response and after parsing it, i'll create a scroll view with internal views and populate the data accordingly. The app is working fine on iPhone. But in Android, its not working peoperly. Unless and until i add the controls to windows, they are not being shown in Android.
I'd like to know if I've to set any thing to work properly in android.
 The following code is used to add the subviews to scroll view:

```
var xPos = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cityCodes.length; i++) 
{
    xPos = i*320;
    var cityImg = require('screens/views').cityDataView(xPos, cityClicked,
        cityCodes.item(i).text,
        cityNames.item(i).text,
        cityExportQuantities.item(i).text,
        exportPercentages.item(i).text,
        populationCount.item(i).text,
        popultionPercentages.item(i).text,
        rates.item(i).text
    );
    scrlView.add(cityImg);
}
```

I'm creating the scroll view as following:

```
scrlView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:'auto', 
    contentHeight:'auto', 
    top:'40%', 
    height:'155dp',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true, 
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:false 
});
```

I'm creating the city data view as following:

```
cityDataView: function(xPos, showCityDetails,  cityCode, cityName, exportQuantity, exportPercent, popCount, popPercent, rate)
{
    var tempLabel = function(topPos,txt){
        // Ti.API.log(topPos);
        var custLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({         
            color:'#000',
        text:txt,
        right:'55%',
        top:topPos,
        font:{
                fontSize:14,
                fontFamily:'GE SS Text Light'
        },
        textAlign:Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,
        width:'auto'
        });
        return custLabel;
    };
    var cityImg = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        left:xPos,
    height : '155dp',
    width : '100%',
    image : '/images/citydetails.png'
    });
    cityImg.addEventListener('singletap', function(){
        Ti.API.log(cityCode);
     showCityDetails(cityCode);
    });
    var cityNameLbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#ffffff',
    text:cityName,
    height:'15dp',
    top:'6%',
    font:{
            fontSize:14,
            fontFamily:'GE SS Text Light'
    },
    textAlign:Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,
    width:'auto'
    });
    cityImg.add(cityNameLbl);
    var exportQtyLbl = tempLabel('19%',exportQuantity);
    cityImg.add(exportQtyLbl);

    var overallProd = tempLabel('35%',exportPercent);
    cityImg.add(overallProd);

    var populationCount = tempLabel('53%',popCount);
    cityImg.add(populationCount);

    var populationPercent = tempLabel('69%',popPercent);
    cityImg.add(populationPercent);

    var rateText = tempLabel('85%',rate);
    cityImg.add(rateText);

    // var totalExportText = tempLabel('95%',totalExport);
    // cityImg.add(totalExportText);

    return cityImg; 
}
```

Comment: @RenePot, I added the sample code.

Comment: Ive had problems with Android support for percentages in the layout of subviews. Maybe try something like this: `var width = Math.round(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth*0.53);` instead of letting Titanium calculate them for you.